# Non-Normal 'Clustered-looking' Residual Plot Interpretation and Fix in Mixed Model

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, residuals

I have linear mixed effects model looking at EEG recordings hourly for 6 hours over 3 conditions (and each subject undergoes each condition) with N=12 animals. I am using lmer in lme4.

Model:

```
model = lmer(EEG ~ Condition*factor(Hour) + (1|Subject)
```

However my residual plot looks like below:

[image]

QQ Plot:

[image]

Is there any way to correct this other than transforming it? Is another type of modeling other than linear mixed models an appropriate route? Any help understanding/interpreting this plot and correcting it greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the regressors are all categorical. That, plus a random intercept might produce something that looks like this w/ no real problems. It's hard to say w/o more information.

Comment: Yes, the condition is categorical. What info would be helpful?